# C++ weird array behaviour

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, for-loop, counting

I was debugging my code for key index counting and found this problem.
I do not understand what is happening here. I've looked at the code for too long to see if I am missing something very obvious, but it does not seem like it.

```
 int main()
{
    const int r=7,len=10;
    int arr[10]={1,4,6,2,0,4,3,6,5,2};
    int count[r+1]={0};
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        count[arr[i]+1]++;
    }
    cout<<arr[0]<<" ";

    for(int i=0;i<r+1;i++)
    {
        count[i+1]+=count[i];
    }
    cout<<arr[0]<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

This is the kind of a mock up code which generates the same bug.

Output:-

> 1 11

I am not changing value of `arr` anywhere in my program and still it shows `11` instead of `1` in the output.

if I comment out `count[arr[i]+1]++;` or `count[i+1]+=count[i];` or both it gives the correct output.

> 1 1

What is happening please explain. (comment if I am doing something silly).

Edit: This is only happening with `arr[0]`.

Comment: Typical buffer overflow issue. Use a debugger to step through the code, statement by statement while monitoring the values of all variables. It helps if you break up complex expression into simpler expressions (like `count[arr[i]+1]++;` could be broken into `int temp = arr[i]; count[temp + 1]++;`).

Comment: As a hint, think about what possible values `i` can be in the second loop. And what index `i + 1` then would be.

Comment: _@Poseidon_ I believe [this compiler warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50974f839a971ded) pretty well explains what's going on. Futile to investigate why code which has undefined behavior, behaves like it does.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh, Thank you I knew I was doing something silly!!!!

Comment: Also, should I delete the question now? I am new to this!!!

Comment: @PoseidonBroger Leave the question alive. It may be a duplicate, but *you* did not find any of the duplicates, so a future person in your position might find this question and thanks to it all the duplicate links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling it with `g++ -Wall -Wextra` you get this warning:

```cpp
rando_so.cpp: In function 'int main()':
rando_so.cpp:15:19: warning: iteration 7 invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
         count[i+1]+=count[i];
         ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
rando_so.cpp:13:18: note: within this loop
     for(int i=0;i<r+1;i++)
```

This hints you to look a bit closer at that second loop. Your variable `i` goes up to the highest possible index of `count` - and then you add 1. That is undefined behaviour. In your case, it is likely that you happen to be writing into the first element of `arr` now, because of how it's laid out on the stack. But as far as I know, *anything* could happen as a result of this.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. the 'anyhting can happen' part is the scariest thing as it might not have affected the program at all(at least that is what i understand) and I would've proceeded with my day.